# Using compare-object in PowerShell to result differences

Tags: powershell

How can I determine the differences between these 2 objects using compare-object ?

```
$traceflags = [pscustomobject]@{
        TraceFlag1 = 10
        Traceflag2 = 20
        Traceflag3 = 30
}


$traceflagsIhave = [pscustomobject]@{
        TraceFlag1 = 20
        Traceflag2 = 30
        Traceflag3 = 40
}

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $traceflags -DifferenceObject $traceflagsIhave
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify _what_ to compare: `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $traceflags -DifferenceObject $traceflagsIhave -Property TraceFlag1,TraceFlag2,TraceFlag3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the cmdlet which properties from both objects you want to compare using [`-Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.4#-property):

```bash
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $traceflags -DifferenceObject $traceflagsIhave -Property TraceFlag1, TraceFlag2, TraceFlag3

# TraceFlag1 TraceFlag2 TraceFlag3 SideIndicator
# ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
#         20         30         40 =>
#         10         20         30 <=
```

---

From feedback in comments, seems like what you're interested in is to find the difference between the **values** of the 2 objects, in which case what you pass as argument to the cmdlet is [`.PSObject.Properties.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psmemberinfo.value?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0#system-management-automation-psmemberinfo-value):

```bash
Compare-Object $traceflags.PSObject.Properties.Value $traceflagsIhave.PSObject.Properties.Value

# InputObject SideIndicator
# ----------- -------------
#          40 =>
#          10 <=
```

And, if you want a sequential comparison, you can include [`-SyncWindow 0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.4#-syncwindow).

Comment: How can I get just the differences between these 2 objects. I mean traceflag have 10,20,30 and traceflagsihave have 20,30,40. The difference between referenceobject and differenceobject is 10

Comment: @LaerteJunior I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you edit your question explaining what you expect? The values of each property is different so the cmdlet outputs every difference between each property

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding how compare object works, I want the differences between these 2 objects which is 10. The referenceobject  have 10,20,30 and the differenceobject  20,30,40 what is missing is 10

Comment: @LaerteJunior I think I understand what you mean, you want the difference between the __values__ of the objects and not which property they belong to. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly my friend :) I can do it using foreach-object but I was wondering if comprae-object can do this for me

Comment: @LaerteJunior see my update, hope that helps

Comment: @LaerteJunior glad it helped :) you can consider accepting the answer unless there is something else missing

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78056682/need-help-using-compare-object