# Need help Using compare-object

Tags: powershell

[image]I have these 2 arrays and I need to get the differences between them

```
$traceIhave = "3226,3042"
$traceIneed =  "3042, 3226, 4199, 7745,8121"

Compare-Object $traceflagsIhave $traceineed
```

I want that show what is missing from traceIneed to traceihave which is 4199, 7745,8121

Even if I use as integer

```
$traceIhave = 3226,3042
$traceIneed =  3042, 3226, 4199, 7745,8121

Compare-Object $traceIhave $traceineed
```

returns

```
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
   3042 =>           
   3226 =>           
   4199 =>           
   7745 =>           
   8121 =>           
3226 3042 <=
```

Can Compare-object  do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Compare-Object` for this task but you would need to split by comma `,` those strings so the cmdlet can compare both arrays. `Trim()` is also used to remove any extra whitespace from each item in the arrays:

```bash
$traceIhave = '3226,3042'
$traceIneed = '3042, 3226, 4199, 7745,8121'

Compare-Object $traceIhave.Split(',').Trim() $traceineed.Split(',').Trim()

# InputObject SideIndicator
# ----------- -------------
# 4199        =>
# 7745        =>
# 8121        =>
```

If you're interested only in the numbers you could use `-PassThru` here.

---

Looking at the edit, it seems what you actually have in `$traceIhave` is actually an array within an array or an *unenumerated array*. This could happen if the cmdlet you're using outputs this array without enumerating it.

Example:

```bash
$traceIhave = , (3226, 3042)
$traceIneed = 3042, 3226, 4199, 7745, 8121

Compare-Object $traceIhave $traceineed

# InputObject SideIndicator
# ----------- -------------
#         3042 =>
#         3226 =>
#         4199 =>
#         7745 =>
#         8121 =>
# {3226, 3042} <=
```

The way you could deal with this is to pipe to `Write-Output` to *unroll* the array. If `$traceIhave` is the result of a command, you can directly pipe it after your command, example:

```bash
$traceIhave = (Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance . -Database master -Query "DBCC TRACESTATUS").traceflag | Write-Output
```

Using the example from before:

```bash
$traceIhave = , (3226, 3042) | Write-Output
$traceIneed = 3042, 3226, 4199, 7745, 8121

Compare-Object $traceIhave $traceineed

# InputObject SideIndicator
# ----------- -------------
#        4199 =>
#        7745 =>
#        8121 =>
```

---

Looking at the newly added screenshot to the question, the only possible explanation for that behavior is that some point your variable `$traceIhave` was constrained to a `[string]`, i.e. `[string] $traceIhave = .....` in which case the solution would have been to constrain it back to an `[int[]]`: `[int[]] $traceIhave = ....`.

Comment: Awesome worked again, but i just realized that is not a string  is a int something like that $traceIhave = 3226,3042 and $traceIneed 3042,3226,4199,8121.  It´s not working when it isa numeric

Comment: @LaerteJunior ahh you have 2 array of integers I see

Comment: Yes, actually one comes from the query os the sql server trace flags. $traceIhave = (Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance . -Database master -Query "DBCC TRACESTATUS").traceflag it returns a integer

Comment: Removing the trim and split is not working

Comment: I think you will need to update your question showing what you actually have because if you have 2 arrays of integers then the cmdlet just works as is: https://i.imgur.com/Qcg7J4j.png. You can use `.GetType()` on both objects to determine what type they are

Comment: done,.. and the gettype from the query is a system.array

Comment: @LaerteJunior hopefully that update helps

Comment: To me is not working, Keeps showing the resul as an image i added

Comment: Ha . I just realized that by the PowerShell ISE is not working but when I open the console works beautiful. Thanks again my friend

Comment: @LaerteJunior I just looked at your screenshot, the only possible explanation for that behavior is that some point your variable `$traceIhave` was constrained to a `[string]`, i.e. `[string] $traceIhave = .....` in which case the solution would have been to constrain it back to an `[int[]]`: `[int[]] $traceIhave = ....`